# Check object is blank

Tags: java

How to check following object is blank or not? I have below class and how could I check that my sample class has nothing data without checking every member of it?

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Sample sample = new Sample();

        if(sample!=null){
            System.out.println("Object is blank..");
        }
    }
}

class Sample {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Comment: You'll need to create a boolean flag and manipulate it in setters,

Comment: If you're worried about code duplication and not about performance, you could add an `isBlank()` method to `Sample` that checks every member, and call that wherever necessary.

Comment: At that point sample will never be null. +1 for @hexafraction

Comment: By "blank", do you mean "has no fields set"? Or do you equate "blank" with `null`?

Comment: I was about to write an answer that did exactly @Michelle 's suggestion... that's the best way to go about it, because then you can define "blank" however you want to.

Comment: @JavaNewbie_M107 That checks whether the object itself is null. I gather OP wants to know whether member variables are blank/null.

Comment: Checking a reference for `null` says nothing about any data an instance might have. Sounds like you need something that actually validates your object's properties.

Comment: Then what about `Objects.requireNonNull()`? [See here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html)

Comment: The OP needs to be more specific about his business requirements for "blank"-ness. Otherwise we can only theorize and come up with a zillion different poorly-constrained solutions.

Answer (score 7):

First you need to define what "blank" means in business terms. What exactly is a "blank" object? Is it an object with a null name? With an empty string name? With some other combination of empty parameters?

Once you've defined what a "blank" object actually is, I recommend adding a method to perform that logic based on the object's current contents and return the results:

```
public boolean isBlank () {
    return ...; // whatever "blank" means
}
```

If possible I advise against using a flag-based approach. While there are certainly valid reasons for it, adding a flag means your setters must maintain the correct value of the flag at all times (and you must also update it after deserialization).

Comment: If the alternative to a flag-based approach is to invent special "empty" values for fields like `id`, that has its own problems, because someone might later decide that the special value you've chosen should be a legitimate value.  I find using flags preferable since it's less "tricky".  An alternative would be to make `id` an Integer object since then it could be null to indicate "no value".

Comment: @ajb There's no need to invent a special "empty" value for an `id` if the business definition of "blank" does not involve the id. It depends if the id is a business key or not. Depending on the usage, you could argue that a blank sample is one with, for example, no name. If the id is not a business key but is, e.g., a database key, then the nameless sample is blank whether its in the database or not. (Of course you could go on to argue that db primary keys should be identical to business keys, but thats another topic).

Comment: And if you *do* include `id` in the definition of blankness the solution would be to use e.g. an `Integer` for the `id`, with `null` signifying "no ID has been assigned", rather than inventing some special integer value.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming that by emptiness of object, you mean that the instance variables are not initialized. I don't think there is any available method to check such emptiness of an object.
If you have to do this, then you may need to write your own method checking the fileds. You should check for the default values of the primitives and null check for object types. An example of such a  method for your class is:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if(this.id == 0 && this.name == null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Please don't consider this as the perfect implementation, so customize as per your need.

Comment: This is a good answer. It's worth stressing to the OP that they must define what "blank" actually means before implementing this method. While that seems obvious, you don't want to teach the OP that he should just blindly check if all fields are 0/null/false.

Comment: This works only if 0 is not a valid `id`.  If a program can call setId(0) legitimately, then you'll need more than the above.  This is a very common programming error.  If setId(0) is wrong then the code for setId should check for this and throw an exception if it gets an invalid id.

Comment: @ajb Good point; that also ties back in to requiring the OP to define what "blank" means. However, if an ID can actually have the state of "not assigned", it would be better to use e.g. an `Integer` for the ID and have `null` signify that, rather than coming up with a special purpose constant value.

Answer (score 3):

One option to create a boolean flag and manipulate it in setters.

Make a private isBlank:

```
private boolean isBlank=true;
```

then have setters call `isBlank=false`. Any setter calls will make the object not blank. Then add a getter `checkIsBlank(` that returns `isBlank`.

Note that the setters should detect a set to null. In that case, they'll need to check all fields. This is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I advise against using a flag approach if possible. There are certainly reasons to use it, but if its possible to check if its blank on the fly based on the current value of fields, then you dont need to maintain the flag from the setters (and you dont need to maintain it after deserialization either). I think this is a valid answer but you should replace "You'll need to" with "One option is to" so as not to mislead the OP.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do, provide a constructor that takes id and name, therefore you know the object will never be blank:

```
public class Sample{
  private int id;
  private String name;

  public Sample(int id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

A hack that you could do with your current class is override the toString method:

```
class Sample {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
      try{
        return Integer.toString(id) + name;
      } catch(Execption e){
        return "";
      }
    }
}

if(sample.toString().isEmpty())
  System.out.println("Object is blank");
```

Comment: This is a very good answer. If you state the invariant that "no blank Sample can exist", putting the required fields in the constructor implicitly guarantees that that is the case (as long as setters also validate input and you can't, e.g., `setName(null); setId(0);` )

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the object is blank by either comparing it to a newly-instantiated object.

```
public boolean isBlank() {
    return this.equals(new Sample());
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    boolean toRet;
    if(o == null || !o instanceof Sample) {
         toRet = false;
    }
    else {
        Sample b = (Sample) o;
        toRet = this.id == b.id 
            && (this.name == null ? b.name == null : this.name.equals(b.name));
    }
    return toRet;
}
```

---

*Old answer:* What you can do is create a *modified* boolean, which is initialized as false, then set to true any time a setter is called.

```
class Sample {
    public static final int INVALID_ID = -1;
    private int id = Sample.INVALID_ID;
    private String name = null;
    private boolean modified = false;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        modified = true;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        modified = true;
    }

    public boolean isModified() { 
        return modified;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would still need a getter for the modified variable.

Comment: Code should include an explanation, either outside the block, or in comments.

Comment: The OP asked how to determine if an object was "blank", not "modified". The key point for the OP is that he needs to define "blank" in business terms.

Comment: @JasonC - Modified == not blank. To clarify, since the original poster did not specify certain conditions for blank, I went with a generalized approach.

Comment: @JasonC Yes, this seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Not if you modify it to be blank. `setName(null); setId(0);`

Comment: @JasonC - I can dig that; I'm going to be modifying my answer in a minute or so

Comment: @hexafraction - I did add an explanation of the code earlier.

Comment: You may also wish to use an `Integer` id and use `null` to mean "unassigned", that way you don't have to come up with a special constant value and risk it conflicting with an actual valid value (and you don't have to maintain that constant across other applications if this is, e.g., in a database or being serialized some other way).

Comment: And one more thing (sorry, another consequence of the flag approach): In order to maintain invariants regarding the definition of the modified flag, you would want to declare `modified` as `transient` and override `readResolve()` to update the flag to the correct value; otherwise an invalid serialized object can break invariants (easy if, say, you are deserializing from XML with e.g. XStream, and you accidentally create an invalid input file by hand; or if you are serializing from another application that misbehaves).